# Can not hide status bar?

Tags: android, statusbar

I want to Hide Status Bar in Android 3.1. 
When user touches on screen, the Status Bar will be visible and after 2 seconds It will be hidden automatically.

Here my code :

```
private static ViewFlipper flipper = null;
private static ImageView ivScreenSnapshot = null;

public static AbsoluteLayout managerField = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    managerField = new AbsoluteLayout(this);

    flipper = new ViewFlipper(this)
    {  
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
        {
            flipper.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE);
            Thread t = new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Global.handler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            flipper.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            t.start();
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
    ivScreenSnapshot = new ImageView(this);
    flipper.addView(managerField);
    flipper.addView(ivScreenSnapshot);
    setContentView(flipper);
    flipper.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
}
```

It's not working, The Status Bar is always visible.
Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="de.vogella.android.temperature"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Convert"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried a code and it worked perfectly. Just for testing, I have called a thread in onCreate() and sent a message to handler to Hide the Status Bar. Below is the code sample. You can use it according to your need.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() 
    {
       public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());

            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
    });

    // start the background thread
    background.start();
}

// handler for the background updating
Handler progressHandler = new Handler() 
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
};
```

Well, using Thread inside onCreate() is not necessary. You can do it without the Thread. Just by calling Thread.Sleep() and sending message to Handler. I hope you can judge the difference in both.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks all,
My code don't work because I have declared android:minSdkVersion = 8 in manfest file.
Now, I edited android:minSdkVersion = 12 and it work fine.